# Google charts, json bad formed and error: not an array

Tags: json, google-visualization

I am trying to pass a json file to render a map with Google Charts. My script code is:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['geomap']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

function drawMap() {
  var dimension = "Clientes";
  var datosMapa;

  $.ajax({
      url:"datosCiudades.json",
      dataType: "JSON"
  }).done (function(data){
    datosMapa = [["City",dimension]];
    $.each(data.datosGeograficos,function(){ //
      var datoCiudad = [this.City,this[dimension]];
      console.log(data.City);
      datosMapa.push(datoCiudad);
    })
  })

  console.log(JSON.stringify(datosMapa));

  var datas = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(datosMapa);

  var options = {};
  options['region'] = 'ES'; //US //154
  options['colors'] = [0xFF8747, 0xFFB581, 0xc06000]; //orange colors
  options['dataMode'] = 'markers';

  var container = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
  var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(container);
  geomap.draw(datas, options);
};
```

And the json file is:

```
{
  "datosGeograficos": [
    {
      "City": "Madrid",
      "Clientes": 200
    },
    {
      "City": "Leon",
      "Clientes": 300
    },
    {
      "City": "Valencia",
      "Clientes": 400
    },
    {
      "City": "Toledo",
      "Clientes": 500
    },
    {
      "City": "Cuenca",
      "Clientes": 600
    },
    {
      "City": "Vigo",
      "Clientes": 700
    }
  ]
}
```

I know that json file is well formed, but I always obtain two answers and I don't see the map. The answers are: "Bad formed", (it refers to json file), and "Error: not an array". The second answer is because don't find the data in json file.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I answered my own question; I put the solution here for other people in the same situation. 
The complete script is:

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['geochart']});
   google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

```
function drawMap() {
  var dimension = "Clientes";
  var datosMapa;

  $.ajax({
      url:"datosCiudades.json",
      dataType: "JSON"
  }).done (function(data){

    datosMapa = [["City","Clientes"]];
    $.each(data.datosGeograficos,function(){ 
      var datoCiudad = [this.City,this.Clientes];
      console.log("datoCiudad: " + datoCiudad); 
      datosMapa.push(datoCiudad);
    })

    var datas = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(datosMapa); 

    var options = {
        region: 'ES', resolution: 'provinces',
        displayMode: 'markers',
        backgroundColor: '#F0F8FF', //color de lo que no son los países
        datalessRegionColor: '#FFEBCD', //color de los países
        defaultColor: '#f5f5f5',
        //displayMode: 'text' , Muestra el texto en vez del círculo.
        colorAxis: {colors: ['#7FFFD4', 'blue']}
    };


    var container = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoChart(container);
    geomap.draw(datas, options);

  })
};
```